# How to generate all months on MDX?

Tags: mdx

Is it possible to generate all months to rows with MDX query?
It look like this if you are using `postgresql`

```
TO_CHAR((current_date - interval '1 month' * a),'MM') AS months
```

Any idea how to do that with MDX?

Answer (score 0):

depending on the confiduration of the cube it can also be very simple:

```
select [Date].[Calendar].[Month].members on 0,
{} on 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Philip,

Comment: Hi @Philip, it says object not found. Should I create [Date] dimension first? If yes, should I have date table on my database? Sorry I'm really new in MDX. Thanks for your response